# Responsive website not being displayed responsively on mobile

Tags: css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

have an annoying issue which I've never experienced before. Building an application using rails and foundation by zurb responsive framework, it's responsive but is not acting so on mobile devices.

I also have a prototype of the website which is not integrated with rails but coded using the same css framework. This version is responsive on mobile devices and is working fine.

Not sure what the issue is, here's the sites:

http://www.devonite.herokuapp.com

http://www.d.cjshort.co.uk

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the head and you should be good.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```